# Improve formatting for the "likes" section on exported resumes

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

This line looks rather jumbled:

[image: Likes: sql-server c# reporting-services asp.net jquery user-experience]

Can we separate each tag that you "like" with `[ ]`'s? For example:

> **Likes:**   [sql-server]  [c#]  [reporting-services]  [asp.net]  [jquery]  [user-experience]

Or maybe style them as tags?

Comment: Separating them with a vertical bar (`|`), or even a comma, would probably be cleaner looking. But the advantage of formatting them as tags would be to make it clear that they were actually tags and you weren't just e e cummings.

Answer (score 14):

I think that an even better way would be to use the tag's [friendly name](/q/335569/6388243) from Documentation, and have them comma-separated. This way, it flows even better, like:

> Likes: C# Language, Java Language, Regular Expressions, apache-spark

Comment: This would work for the most common tags that have Documentation created for them, but I don't think all tags have associated Documentation [yet?]. Naturally, these would be the tags people are least likely to include on their CV, but we would still need to handle that case. I guess you'd fall back to the literal tag name. Also, I'm not sure I like the "Language" part. I'd never write it that way if it were a free-form field.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, I don't like the friendly names having "Language" added on either, but I can't do anything about that.

Comment: Maybe the simple answer is dont do this, leave it as is, just add a `,` (comma) to each like?